# Laravel: сортировка выборки по связи и высчитываемому свойству

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Я использую Laravel вместе с пакетом spatie/laravel-query-builder. У меня есть модели карты и платежа. Мне нужно сделать выборку карт, отсортировав их по сумме платежей за текущие сутки. Для этого я использую пакет [spatie/laravel-query-builder](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v5/features/sorting#content-custom-sorts), но это не так важно. По сути, это просто обёртка над билдером запроса. Чтобы понять проблему сначала нужно посмотреть на то как я пытаюсь решить задачу. Вот мои модели и сервисы:

Модель карты:

```
class Card extends Model {
    protected $appends = [
        'today_import',
    ];

    public function payments(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(
            related: Payment::class,
            foreignKey: 'card',
            localKey: 'number');
    }

    public function getTodayImportAttribute(): float
    {
        return $this->payments()->incoming()->ofThisDay()->sum('sum');
    }
}
```

Модель платежа

```
class Payment extends Model {

    protected $casts = [
        'sum' => 'decimal:2',
        'date' => 'datetime'
    ];

    public function scopeIncoming(Builder $query): Builder
    {
        return $query->where('type', 'In');
    }

    public function scopeOfThisDay(Builder $query): Builder
    {
        return $query->where('date', '>', Carbon::now()->startOfDay());
    }
}
```

Сервис:

```
class ShowCardsService
{
    public function __construct(protected array $data = [])
    {
        $this->data = Validator::validate($data, [
            'cur_page' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1'],
            'per_page' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1']
        ]);
    }

    public function execute(): LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        return QueryBuilder::for(
            Card::class
        )->allowedSorts([
            AllowedSort::custom('today_import', new SortByTodayImport()),
        ])->paginate(
            perPage: $this->data['per_page'],
            page: $this->data['cur_page']
        );
    }
}
```

А ниже кастомный сортировщик, внутри которого должна быть логика сортировки

```
use Spatie\QueryBuilder\Sorts\Sort;

class SortByTodayImport implements Sort
{
    public function __invoke(Builder $query, bool $descending, string $property)
    {
        // Что тут писать?

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Я совершенно не понимаю что нужно прописать в сортировщике. Пытался поставить задачу ИИ, но результата не было. Понимаю, что запрос будет тяжелым, но иного выхода я не знаю. По всей видимости, нужно делать вложенный запрос, который бы высчитывал сумму платежей, но что именно прописать мне не ведомо.

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено и выглядит следующим образом:

```
class SortByTodayImport implements Sort
{
    public function __invoke(Builder $query, bool $descending, string $property)
    {
        return $query->leftJoin('payments', function ($join) {
            $join->on('cards.number', '=', 'payments.card')
                ->where('payments.type', '=', 'In')
                ->where('payments.date', '>', Carbon::now()->startOfDay());
        })
            ->select('cards.*', DB::raw('SUM(payments.sum) as today_import'))
            ->groupBy('cards.id')
            ->orderBy('today_import', $descending ? 'DESC' : 'ASC');
    }
}
```

Жаль, что не получилось использовать уже прописанные связи и скопы моделей.